# SQL Query - GROUP BY SUM hangs where no elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I try to run the query:

```
SELECT statement_element_statement_id, sum(statement_element_commission_amount_change)
  FROM [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_element_commissions]
  JOIN [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_elements]
    on [statelemt_element_commission_se_id] = statement_element_id  
  WHERE statement_element_statement_id in 
  (10258, 10226, 10225, 10224, 10223, 
  10220, 10219, 10218, 10217, 10216)
  GROUP BY statement_element_statement_id
```

10258, 10226, 10225, 10224, 10223 - these ids has elements

10220, 10219, 10218, 10217, 10216 - there ids has no elements

When I run this query I can get 5 results:

```
SELECT statement_element_statement_id, sum(statement_element_commission_amount_change)
  FROM [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_element_commissions]
  JOIN [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_elements]
    on [statelemt_element_commission_se_id] = statement_element_id  
  WHERE statement_element_statement_id in 
  (10258, 10226, 10225, 10224, 10223)
  GROUP BY statement_element_statement_id
```

[image]

How to handle hanging when group by can sometimes not find elements for particular id in where statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle hanging"?

Comment: You would like to have those numbers 10220, ... (without element) in the result?

Comment: I expect 5 rows with numeric results, 5 rows without result or even not appearing. My query freezes when at least one of 5 elements (10220, 10219, 10218, 10217, 10216) appears. EDIT: added screen with only 5 elements in query where all of them has the records

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"

Comment: @Staly In your screenshots it appears to be working fine. You're getting 5 results, 1 for each ID you group by

Comment: @Magisch - yes, but as you can see I commented out 5 problematic IDs. When I uncomment them, query freezes.

Comment: @Staly can you post the raw data you're taking this from (both tables)? Otherwise we can't reproduce

Comment: Even with your join this shouldn't be freezing.

Comment: With 5 parameters query runs for less than 1 second, adding 5 problematic IDs makes 1-minute run to achieve results.

Comment: Can you post the query plan?

Comment: Which table has statement_element_statement_id column?

Comment: @sarslan ws_statement_elements has statement_element_statement_id column

Comment: @Staly then [ws_statement_elements] table should be on left side. look at my answer

Comment: @Staly, If the answer are ok, can you upvote (one or many answer) and mark as resolve your preferred answer. Thanks for Sarlsan and me. bye.

Answer (score 1):

Use a right join  (or inverse the order and use a left join):

```
SELECT
    statement_element_statement_id, 
    sum(statement_element_commission_amount_change)
FROM
    [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_element_commissions]
    RIGHT JOIN [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_elements] on
        [statelemt_element_commission_se_id] = statement_element_id  
WHERE
    statement_element_statement_id in (
        10258, 10226, 10225, 10224, 10223, 
        10220, 10219, 10218, 10217, 10216
    )
GROUP BY
    statement_element_statement_id
```

Comment: nvl is coalesce in MSSQL, didn't help

Comment: statement_element_commission_amount_change is in table ws_statement_element_commissions, you don't need nvl or coalesce

Comment: `coalesce` or  `isnull` are required if you want a default value

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I think [ws_statement_elements] table should be at the left side.

```
SELECT statement_element_statement_id, SUM(ISNULL(statement_element_commission_amount_change,0) )
  FROM [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_elements]
        LEFT JOIN [chester-prod].[dbo].[ws_statement_element_commissions]
    on [statelemt_element_commission_se_id] = statement_element_id  
  WHERE statement_element_statement_id in 
  (10258, 10226, 10225, 10224, 10223, 
  10220, 10219, 10218, 10217, 10216)
  GROUP BY statement_element_statement_id
```

Comment: It takes 50 seconds to make complete request.

Comment: How the result before?

Comment: It was between 50-60 seconds.

Comment: Is it about your question? I mean performance problems are other aspects of your query.